# How to trigger the bird's special abilities using Apple Magic Trackpad

Tags: angry-birds

Trying out Angry Birds from the new iMac app store.

I'm unable to activate the blue bird's power (to split into 3 birds) using my Magic trackpad.  I've tried most every gesture I could imagine with no luck.  Their help documentation doesn't appear to have been updated for this version.

How can I trigger the ability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To 'activate' the bird, click the trackpad.